# check for Protractor truth, toBeTruthy on a Protractor method, click()

Tags: angular, protractor

I am curious if a click method's ability to click and icon is valid when you have code simiilar to:

```
expect(element(by.id('elementToClick')).click()).toBeTruthy();
```

I'm not sure about elementToBeClickable(), anyone try that on an icon that exists, is visible, yet is disabled for a click( style="pointer-events: none;").  I haven't really had a chance to test elementToBeClickable() yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code:

```
expect(element(by.id('elementToClick')).click()).toBeTruthy();
```

seems to work.  After I disabled the href with the 'pointer-events:none'.  It returned a false.  I guess I had to have the correct luck and code.  Thanks for an attempt user8019967.

Answer (score 0):

This might be of help

componentDebugElement.query(By.css('elementToClick')).triggerEventHandler('click', null)

Comment: It should. Depends on whether or not your version of protractor supports Jasmine